# unable to scrape data due to buggy html code

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, lxml

I am trying to get the phone number the html code is

`<span>
<a class="click-to-call-link text-gray-light trackMe" href="javascript:;" objid="1236535" compid="clickToCall_profile_directory_sponsored" phone="(617) 981-6551"">Click to Call
</a>
</span>`

The phone number has two double quotes at the end. This makes it difficult to fetch using lxml.
Is there a way to get this attribute.
When i use the xpath of span and print thee results it shows `<Element span at 0x3750060>`but when i add anchoe tag to the xpath it throws an error.

Comment: So, you have an xpath that fails.... post that xpath and the error message! From that example I can do xpath `/span/a` successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You want [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

> Beautiful Soup is a Python library for pulling data out of HTML and
>   XML files. It works with your favorite parser to provide idiomatic
>   ways of navigating, searching, and modifying the parse tree.

In short, it deals with poorly formed HTML and XML and makes it more useful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to get the phone number in this way.

```
>>> HTML
'<span><a class="click-to-call-link text-gray-light trackMe" href="javascript:;" objid="1236535" compid="clickToCall_profile_directory_sponsored" phone="(617) 981-6551" "="">Click to Call</a></span>'
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> parser = etree.HTMLParser()
>>> tree = etree.fromstring(HTML, parser=parser)
>>> link = tree.xpath('.//a')
>>> link
[<Element a at 0x5a15e08>]
>>> link[0].attrib['phone']
'(617) 981-6551'
```

You can obtain the phone number from the whole page using this code. The only tricky bits are the `xpath` and in remembering that the `xpath` will return a list.

```
>>> import requests
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> page = requests.get('https://www.houzz.com/pro/charlesrose/charles-rose-architects-inc').text
>>> parser = etree.HTMLParser()
>>> tree = etree.fromstring(page, parser=parser)
>>> links = tree.xpath('.//a[@class="click-to-call-link text-gray-light trackMe"]')
>>> links[0].attrib['phone']
'(617) 981-6551'
```

Comment: I tried using this method and I am still unable to get the result. It returns an empty list. The webpage that I am trying to get is https://www.houzz.com/pro/charlesrose/charles-rose-architects-inc

Comment: looks like i posted the wrong html . I have edited it now

Comment: The original code still works for the updated HTML. I have added code that works for the page downloaded from the web.

Comment: I just ran it twice. The first time there were no results, the second time it worked. It might be that all you can do is to build your code to allow for this kind of unreliability.

Comment: umm well i ran it around 20 times and it still returns an empty list

Comment: I'm not being flippant when I say, at least it's consistent and that should make it easier to debug. Have you examined the HTML that `requests` downloads to verify that it has what you want? As someone else has suggested you could instead try BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 0):

Use Beautiful Soup with html.parser can parse faulty html string.

```
body = '<span>\n<a class="click-to-call-link text-gray-light trackMe" href="javascript:;" objid="1236535" compid="clickToCall_profile_directory_sponsored" phone="(617) 981-6551" "="">Click to Call\n</a>\n</span>'
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(body, 'html.parser')
soup.find('a').get('phone')
```

Comment: Doesn't this only get the attribute from the first tag it finds of that name. For Example in this it gets the phone attribute of the first <a> it encounters. and if the first <a> dosn't have phone attribute then it shows nothing

Comment: BTW this is the website I want the phone number from.
https://www.houzz.com/pro/charlesrose/charles-rose-architects-inc

Comment: looks like i posted the wrong html . I have edited it now

Comment: @AdityaShekhawat  use your new html and it still works.
If you need to get all <a> under this html string, you can do like soup.find_all('a') and use a loop to iterating every <a>.